Exception when the user try to login with Federate authentication in wso2is version 5.11
maybe someone can help me with an error that i have with wso2is v5.11:
I had configured a basic authenticator and two Federated authenticators in wso2 IS 5.11.0 but i have a stranger behavior when the user try to login to one of those two federate system; specifically sometimes, after the user put username and password the authentication flow doesn't work an the user see again the login page where he/she have to insert again the username and password.
Aftert that, the second time that user put the username and password he/she can login inside the system.This problem is intermittent, i mean, when the user try to do it ten time for example, it happens just one time.
Inside the log in wso2carbon i have this :
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Exception in Authentication Framework org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.exception.FrameworkException: No authenticator can handle the request in step :  1
Could someone help me on that?
I attach here my console configuration:



